# gorm entity with multiple constrains

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

```
class Book {

String name
String author       
 static constraints = { name(nullable:true) 
}
}
```

The above seems to work, however when i put in constraints for multiple fields the server does not start up

```
class Book {

String name
String author       
 static constraints = { name(nullable:true) author(nullabe:false)
}
}
```

With the above code ... I get the below exception

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedPrope
>   rty.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty) values: [org.codehau
>   s.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty@3343e5[class com.nthdimenzion.domain.Book,author,class java.lang.String,{nulla
>   ble=org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.NullableConstraint@1aea6e2[false]}]]
>   Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), isUrl()
>           at com.nthdimenzion.domain.Book$_*clinit*_closure1.doCall(Book.groovy:16)
>           at com.nthdimenzion.domain.Book$_*clinit*_closure1.doCall(Book.groovy)
>           ... 23 more

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you have it on the same line...

try

```
 static constraints = { 
    name(nullable:true) 
    author(nullabe:false)
 }
```

EDIT:

You can alos separate the entries with `;` then you can have it all on one line if that is what you want. (however i think the majority of us don't use oneliners...)

Comment: Thanks that was the problem :)